# How to transform a string column to a list of string list column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({'names': ['John;Joe;Tom', 'Justin', 'Ryan;John']})

    names
0   John;Joe;Tom
1   Justin
2   Ryan;John
```

I want to transform the column to a string list column like below:

```
0    ['John', 'Joe', 'Tom']
1            ['Justin']
2        ['Ryan', 'John']
```

I did the following:

```
df.names.apply(lambda x: x.split(';'))
```

what I got is:

```
0    [John, Joe, Tom]
1            [Justin]
2        [Ryan, John]
```

I lost all the quotes.  Does anyone know how to fix that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You didn't _lose the quotes_, you can check the values yourself and see that it isn't the case. Notice how the elements in the DataFrame before splitting don't have any quotes either. Also, you should use `df["names"].str.split(";")` to split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never lost the quotes.
It is just because pandas do not show the quotes for two or more rows.
Check the following example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({'names': ['John;Joe;Tom', 'Justin', 'Ryan;John']})
df.names = df.names.apply(lambda x: x.split(';'))
df.names.iloc[0]
```

The output is `['John', 'Joe', 'Tom']` as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

As Gilseung mentioned, the output is same as your output. But if you really insist adding quotes as an extra character to you output try this:

```
def add(x):
    temp_list = x.split(';')
    temp_list = [f"\'{x}\'" for x in temp_list]       #adds extra character
    return temp_list

df = df.names.apply(add)
```

which gives you this output:

```
0    ['John', 'Joe', 'Tom']
1                ['Justin']
2          ['Ryan', 'John']
Name: names, dtype: object
```